# OnTriggerEnter, the score isn't calculated correctly. What's wrong with my script?

Tags: user-interface, unity-game-engine

Here's the script I'm using:

```
function OnTriggerEnter( other : Collider ) 
{
    if (other.tag == "Coins")
    {
        score = score + 5;
        Debug.Log("Player Score" + score);
        Destroy(other.gameObject);
    }
}

function OnGUI () 
{
    GUI.Box (Rect (10,35,120,30), "Player Score : " + Mathf.Round(score));
}
```

The problem is that when I enter the trigger of the coin, it doesn't go + 5.
Sometimes it goes all of a sudden + 10 or + 15. Resulting in a higher score than intended.

Here's an example where I collected only two coins and instead of getting a score of 10, I got 20.

http://imgur.com/z1xqgrh

Comment: Theres nothing wrong with your code, check and make sure you only have 1 collider in your object, you can also check the name of object that is entering collider.

Comment: It seems I didn't have just 1 collider. Thanks for you reply!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have more than one collider in the collided object hierarchy.

Take a look at this [Layer-Based Collision Detection document](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Components/LayerBasedCollision.html). It explains how you can create only one collider in one layer and make all collisions happening in that specific layer only, thus activating only that single collider.